# Jquery issue with IE 9

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I'm getting the following error when i'm trying to implement the drag and drop functionality in IE 9 browser.it works fine in google crome and fire fox

```
Microsoft Jscript runtime error:unable to get value of the property 'prototype'.object is null or undefined
```

error occurs at ui.mouse.js 
any one know the solution?

Comment: which jquery(and UI) version are you using?

Comment: use the latest version of UI. hope it will help you

Comment: you should delete the question or move your solving comment to an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js and
>   jquery-1.5.1.min.js version solved the
>   issue.